# How to pass more tha 2 variables to laravel view

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have a controller that has 3 tables of data that I want to pass to a view page but view() only accepts 2 variables

```
    public function createShowTime(){
    
            $eventdays = Eventday::all();
            $movies = Movie::all();
            $showtimes = Showtime::all();
            return view('admin.layouts.createshowtime', ["eventdays" => $eventdays], ["movies" => $movies], ["showtimes" => $showtimes]);
        }
```

the problem here is that view() doesn't accept the third variable which is ["showtimes" => $showtimes] so how can I pass it?

Comment: Have you had a read of the [Laravel views documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't send it as separate arrays, you can send it as a single associative arrays like this:

```
    public function createShowTime(){
    
            $eventdays = Eventday::all();
            $movies = Movie::all();
            $showtimes = Showtime::all();
            return view('admin.layouts.createshowtime', ["eventdays" => $eventdays, "movies" => $movies, "showtimes" => $showtimes]);
        }
```

Read more about [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#passing-data-to-views)

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
public function createShowTime(){
    
            $eventdays = Eventday::all();
            $movies = Movie::all();
            $showtimes = Showtime::all();
            return view('admin.layouts.createshowtime')->with('eventdays',$eventdays)->with('movies',$movies)->with('showtimes',$showtimes);
        }
```

you can also do this with another way

```
public function createShowTime(){
        
                $eventdays = Eventday::all();
                $movies = Movie::all();
                $showtimes = Showtime::all();
                return view('admin.layouts.createshowtime',compact('eventdays','movies','showtimes'));
```